# Can't POST data through Angular $resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, web, factory

I'm trying to figure out how to pass data to an API through Angular's `$resource`.  I can `GET` or query any data from my test server currently, but I also want to see how to `POST` new data to the server.  I am using this code that I've adapted from the AngularJS docs:

```
.factory("ResourceTest", function($resource) {
    return $resource("http://mywebsite.com/api/:id", {id:'1'}, {
        charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
    });
});
```

When I run `ResourceTest.charge();` in my controller, it works fine, and I see a `POST` request in my server logs.  But when I try to pass any parameters when I call the function (eg `ResourceTest.charge({test:false});`), the request will not go through, and I can't see any request in the logs. (same happens with `.save()`, in case anyone is wondering)

Anyone know if it's just a code error I'm making here? I'm pretty new to AngularJS.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh and also - I AM able to post data using `$http`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are pulling from the angular docs to try and get resource up and running.  I had quite a time myself and didn't find the docs to very helpful in understanding ngResource and how to correctly implement it.

This article clears things up quite a bit:

http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out.  The request headers needed to be changed, apparently.  Here's the code I added to make it work, hope it helps someone else out.

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post  = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect the $resource object to do?

If you pass in a data object to the $resource charge function it will send the data as the request payload to the url you defined. See working example below.

```
myApp.factory("ResourceTest", function($resource) {
    return $resource("http://mywebsite.com/api/:id", {id:'1'}, {
        charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
    });
});
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, ResourceTest) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.test = function (userInput) {
        console.log("check the browser console Network > XHR to see the request payload");
        ResourceTest.charge({'userInput':userInput});
    }
});
```

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/joshvito/qd7ap4jg/25/)